# Is it necessary to have a co_return statement on each execution path of a coroutine that returns void

Tags: c++, coroutine, c++-winrt, c++-coroutine

I wonder whether the below code is valid C++ code or if not using `co_return` results in undefined behavior.

```cpp
IAsyncAction MyClass::MyCoroutine()
{
  co_await someOtherClassInstance.SomeCoroutine();
}
```

I.e. is it necessary to adjust the code as follows?

```cpp
IAsyncAction MyClass::MyCoroutine()
{
  co_await someOtherClassInstance.SomeCoroutine();
  co_return;
}
```

If the behavior is not undefined, what is the best practice (always add `co_return` or not) and what is the justification for doing so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Omitting the `co_return;` statement is well defined here. According to [[stmt.return.coroutine]](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return.coroutine#3) this is allowed as long as `p.return_void()` is a valid expression (where `p` is the promise type).

C++/WinRT implements `return_void()` for [`IAsyncAction`](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/fb9ef7b9194a1f29578bf6b9329089e88c58c01c/strings/base_coroutine_foundation.h#L694-L696) and [`IAsyncActionWithProgress`](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt/blob/fb9ef7b9194a1f29578bf6b9329089e88c58c01c/strings/base_coroutine_foundation.h#L719-L721) (or rather the internal await adapter structs for those).

Since the `co_return;` statement is purely optional here, it is down to personal preference on whether to use it or not. Personally, I prefer reading code where the `co_return;` statement is present, for a few reasons:

- It allows me to easily comment out part of the coroutine (e.g. for testing) without risking to turn it into a regular function.
- I don't have to know the intricacies of the complex C++/WinRT library to figure out whether the code is correct.
- The code stays correct if I ever decide to change its return type.

Answer (score 1):

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines), the first block would only incur in undefined behaviour if the Promise type has no `Promise::return_void()` member function:

> When a coroutine reaches the `co_return` statement, it performs the
> following:
>
> - calls `promise.return_void()` for
>
>   - `co_return;`
>   - `co_return expr` where `expr` has type void
>   - **falling off the end of a void-returning coroutine.** The behavior is **undefined if** the Promise type has **no `Promise::return_void()`** member
>     function in this case.

The [Standard draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return.coroutine#3) seems to say the same in other words:

> **If `p.return_­void()` is a valid expression, flowing off the end of a coroutine's function-body is equivalent to a `co_­return` with no
> operand;** otherwise flowing off the end of a coroutine's function-body
> results in undefined behavior.

[Emphasis mine in both quotes]